# Solve the problem during publish localhost with ngrok

Tags: vue.js, ngrok

I am going to launch my local Vue application with ngrok. 
I used this command.

```
ngrok http 8080
```

It says online. 
 
[image]

But when I visit this site, it shows error. 
[image]

This is the output from the ngrok.
[image]

I think the problem is HTTPS. My local version is HTTPS.
Here is the screenshot.
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can u try ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 8080

Comment: Please could you check/show the output from the ngrok [web interface](http://localhost:4040) after attempting to navigate to the Vue app?

Comment: Hi @VenkateshA! Thank you for  your message. I tried with that command, but the result is the same. It shows ngrok gateway error.

Comment: Hi @ant! I insert the ngrok output to the question. Please have a check. What else do you want to check? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `ngrok http https://localhost:8080`? https://ngrok.com/docs#http-local-https

Comment: @lossleader, it doesn't work. It shows an Invalid header error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngrok assumes that the server it is forwarding to is listening for unencrypted HTTP traffic, but if your server is listening for encrypted HTTPS traffic you can specify a URL with an https:// scheme to request that ngrok speak HTTPS to your local server.

**Forward to an https server by specifying the https:// scheme**

```
ngrok http https://localhost:8080
```

As a special case, ngrok assumes that if you forward to port 443 on any host that it should send HTTPS traffic and will act as if you specified an https:// URL.

**Forward to the default https port on localhost**

```
ngrok http 443
```

ngrok assumes that your local network is private and it does not do any validation of the TLS certificate presented by your local server.

**If need be, explicitly direct to https locally.**

```
ngrok http https://localhost:8080 -host-header="localhost:8080"
```

Comment: I tried with your commands, but it says `Invalid Host header`

Comment: explicitly direct to https locally. e.g. `ngrok http https://localhost:8080 -host-header="localhost:8080"`

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you. Would you like to update your answer with this command, plz?
So I can accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try ngrok without http
And use node js code to mark -8080 port as your server address

```
    const ngrok = require('ngrok');

   (async function() {
   const url = await ngrok.connect(8080);
   })();
```

When you'll run this this will create a url use that url to access your server

Comment: Hi Vicky!
Thank you for your answer.
But, I am not using node.js. My application is Vue.js. 
Can I launch this application without node.js?

Answer (score -1):

The main problem is that you don't have a valid **ssl certificate on localhost**.
You need to expose the normal **http** not the **https**. I think it is going to work eg:

```
ngrok http http://localhost:8080
```

And in the vue server try to avoid the ssl or https encryption.